# Highchart: How to get the data array of the stacks per column?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prJjY/277/)

```
yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
        enabled:true,
        formatter: function(){
            return this.axis.series;
        }
    }   
}
```

So far, what am I getting is the array object? Not sure about it .

> [object object],[object object]

What I wanted o get is the data array or the value on that array

> [[1](http://jsfiddle.net/prJjY/277/)],[3] or [1,3] instead of that [object object],[object object] shown above .

I wanted to display this value on the top of the stacks column and not the total of that stack..
I don't know if my logic is correct but what I really wanted to do is Let say 1 stack column has 3 data's . Each of them has a value of 100. Normally if I do "this.total" it would return 300. But what I want is to create a function that will get the 20% of each data "if they belong to that series" . and then sum it up.

for example on series1, value is = series1*0.1, on series2, value is = series2*0.2 and on series3, value is = series3*0.5. Let say that the total value of series1 = 100; series2 = 200, series3 = 300. the total of that stack column should be "200" // series1=10 + series2 = 40 + series3 = 150

Comment: Can you post screenshot of what yo uwant

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir actually, I tried to add a screenshot but stacks don't let me, saying that I need to have 10 reputations to do so.. kindly check it here - [screenshot](http://ctrlv.in/623507)